# C# - Using a private setter with a public getter on reference types

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation, getter-setter, reference-type

Consider the following short code example with a public getter and a private setter:

```
public class Foo        
{
    public class Bar
    {
        ...
    }

    public Bar fooBar { get; private set; }
    public int valueType { get; private set; }
}
```

I want to make sure that the class members can only be written to from inside the `Foo` class. That works for value types like `valueType` in the example above. But how do reference types like the nested class `fooBar` behave?

Can I use the reference which is returned by the public getter, to manipulate my private member?

Comment: You are correct, the private setter will only protect Foo's reference, and not the actual class instance it references.

Comment: The best approach is to make `Bar` [immutable](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the type you're referring to is mutable, then yes, anyone with a reference to the "container" can fetch a reference and then mutate the object. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Container
{
    public List<string> List { get; private set; }
        = new List<string>();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        var list = container.List;
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count); //0

        container.List.Add("foo");
        Console.WriteLine(list.Count); // 1        
    }
}
```

Here the `List<string>` is being mutated outside `Container`. One option to avoid this would be to use a read-only view over the mutable data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Container
{
    private readonly List<string> list = new List<string>();

    public IReadOnlyList<string> ListView { get; }

    public Container()
    {
        ListView = list.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        Console.WriteLine(container.ListView.Count); //0

        // container.ListView.Add("foo"); // Compile-time error

        container.AddItem("foo");
        Console.WriteLine(container.ListView.Count); // 1        
    }
}
```

Note that you shouldn't just return the list directly from the property, even if the compile-time type is `IReadOnlyList<T>` - because then a caller could just cast back to `List<T>` and mutate it. `List<T>.AsReadOnly()` returns a genuinely read-only wrapper object around the list, so callers really won't be able to mutate it.

Comment: the private list does not **have to** be read-only. It's enough for the property to return list.AsReadOnly(); to achieve the required aspect. right?

Comment: @Nina: If the `list` field isn't readonly, then something could potentially change which list it refers to, at which point the `ListView` property is effectively invalidated - it will keep giving a reference to a wrapper around the *old* list.

Comment: the **readonly** modifier in this case will just prevent assigning a completely different list to the list field, but will not prevent modifying the original list by adding and removing items. Did I get it right ?

Comment: @Nina: Yes, exactly.